# Is there an official manual for zparseopts?

Tags: shell, zsh

Is there an official manual for `zparseopts`?

I've tried ZSH man pages and Google, with no big success.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The man page entry for `zparseopts` can be found in [`zshmodules(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshmodules).

Comment: However, you might want to look at `man zshmodules` instead since the link above is outdated. For example, the flag `-F` is not documented there.

Comment: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html (many of the zsh help pages packs annoyingly many commands/concepts in the same page making search painful..)